# Creating a timer on event in Warcraft in Lua

Tags: events, timer, lua

I'm looking for help checking for when the event "SPELL_INTERRUPT" fires so I can display a timer in the game World of Warcraft.

This is [the code](https://codeshare.io/G7wNbG) so far

```
local SPELL_LOCKOUTS = {
-- [interruptSpellID] = lockoutDuration, -- Spell Name (Class)

 [2139] = 6, -- Counterspell (Mage)
 [1766] = 5, -- Kick (Rogue)
 [96231] = 4, -- Rebuke (Paladin)
 [147362] = 3, -- Counter Shot (Hunter)
 [6552] = 4, -- Pummel (Warrior)
 [115781] = 6, -- Optical Blast (Warlock)
 [47528] = 4, -- Mind Freeze (Death Knight)
 [19647] = 6, -- Spell Lock (Warlock)
 [173320] = 5, -- Spear Hand Strike (Monk)
 [2139] = 6, -- Counterspell (Mage)
 [106839] = 4, -- Skull Bash (Druid)
 [57994] = 3, -- Wind Shear (Shaman)
 [187707] = 3, -- Muzzle (Hunter)
 [183752] = 3, -- Consume Magic (Demon Hunter)
}

-- If this is "DBM", DBM's timers will be used. If this is "SW", Blizzard's stopwatch will be used.
local MODE = "DBM"

-- The text to display on DBM Timers.
-- %SPELL% will be replaced with the name of the interrupt spell you cast.
-- %ISPELL% will be replaced with the name of the spell you interrupted
-- %DUR% will be replaced with the duration of the lockout.

local BARTEXT = "%SPELL% interrupted %ISPELL%. Locked out for %DUR% seconds"
-------------------
-- END OF CONFIG --
-------------------

local ARENA1_GUID;
local ARENA2_GUID;
local ARENA3_GUID;
local TARGET_GUID;
local PLAYER_GUID;

local ShowTimer; -- Declare the ShowTimer variable as local

if MODE == "DBM" and DBM then -- If MODE is "DBM" and there's a global variable DBM

 local DBM = DBM -- Create a local alias to DBM
 local gsubTable = {} -- This table is used to handle text substitutions with gsub

 ShowTimer = function(seconds, interruptSpell, interruptedSpell) -- Define the ShowTimer function
 gsubTable.SPELL = interruptSpell -- Populate the fields of the table
 gsubTable.ISPELL = interruptedSpell
 gsubTable.DUR = seconds
 local text = BARTEXT:gsub("%%(%a+)%%", gsubTable) -- Replace each occurrence of %SPELL%, %ISPELL% or %DUR% with the corresponding field of gsubTable and assing the result to the text variable

 DBM:CreatePizzaTimer(seconds, text) -- Create the timer
 end

else -- Either MODE isn't "DBM", or there's no global variable DBM

 ShowTimer = function(seconds)
 Stopwatch_StartCountdown(0, 0, seconds)
 Stopwatch_Play()
 end

end

local f = CreateFrame("Frame") -- Create a frame and register some events.
f:RegisterEvent("PLAYER_ENTERING_WORLD")
f:RegisterEvent("COMBAT_LOG_EVENT_UNFILTERED")
f:SetScript("OnEvent", function(self, event, ...) -- Every time an event we're watching fires, call the corresponding method of the frame (e.g. PLAYER_ENTERING_WORLD calls f:PLAYER_ENTERING_WORLD() )
 self[event](self, ...)
end)

function f:PLAYER_ENTERING_WORLD() -- This fires towards the end of the intitial login process.
 ARENA1_GUID = UnitGUID("arena1") -- Record the arena1 GUID
 ARENA2_GUID = UnitGUID("arena2") -- Record the arena2 GUID
 ARENA3_GUID = UnitGUID("arena3") -- Record the arena3 GUID
 TARGET_GUID = UnitGUID("target") -- Record the Target's GUID
 PLAYER_GUID = UnitGUID("player") -- Record the player's GUID
 self:UnregisterEvent("PLAYER_ENTERING_WORLD") -- Unregister this event, we don't care about it any more.
end

-- This fires any time someone does something combat-related near the player
function f:COMBAT_LOG_EVENT_UNFILTERED(timestamp, event, hideCaster, sourceGUID, sourceName, sourceFlags, sourceRaidFlags, destGUID, destName, destFlags, destRaidFlags, ...)

 local spellId, spellName, spellSchool, extraSpellID, extraSpellName, extraSchool = ... -- Get the extra arguments from the vararg
 local lockout = SPELL_LOCKOUTS[spellId] -- Check if we have a lockout time for this interrupt spell

 if lockout then -- If we do, show a timer.
 ShowTimer(lockout, spellName, extraSpellName)
 end
end
```

The timer displays but will display whether or not the interrupt actually interrupted a spell. I need it to show the timer ONLY after a spell has been interrupted by one of the spellID's specified in `SPELL_LOCKOUTS`.

I know that in the last few lines (line 81 through 86) I need to add an `and` statement but I don't quite know how to phrase it.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: http://wowwiki.wikia.com/wiki/API_COMBAT_LOG_EVENT

additional resources

Answer (score 2):

I was answered by someone on the game. It needed to be changed from

```
    if lockout then Showtimer
```

to

```
    if lockout and event=="SPELL_INTERRUPT" then Showtimer
```